# watchOS2で、Watch Extension側に、iOSアプリ側からNSUserDefaults経由で、データが渡ってこない。

Tags: swift

iOSアプリ側 [ViewController.swift]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let udForWatch = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: SuiteName)!
        let ary = ["テスト","テスト"]

        udForWatch.setObject(ary, forKey: "ary")
}
```

Watch Extension側 [InterfaceController.swift]

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {


        override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
            super.awakeWithContext(context)

            let ud = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: SuiteName)!
            print(ud.objectForKey("ary")) //nilになる。

        }
    }
```

としているのですが、Watch Extension側のデータがnilになってしまいます。
何がおかしいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

watchOS2ではWatchConnectivityを使用する必要があります。上記のコードはいわゆるwatchOS1でしか使うことができません。

こちらでその原因が述べられていますが、watchOS1ではiPhoneでExtensionが動作していましたが、watchOS2からはApple Watchで動作するようになったためです。
http://qiita.com/koogawa/items/432b9c65035b6ba17c8b#3-app-groups%E3%81%A7%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92%E5%85%B1%E6%9C%89%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C

iPhone内に保存したUserDefaultsのデータはWatchConnectivityフレームワークの`sendMessage`など、用途に応じて適切な方法で送信する必要があります。
http://qiita.com/koogawa/items/b39e1419cbbcda8efc07

Comment: WatchConnectivityを使ったらできました！ありがとうございます！